# Update windows service environment variables

Tags: windows, windows-services

I've update `Path` environment variable (changed existing path) and restarted Windows service, but it still sees old `Path` value. I discovered that Windows service inherits its environment variables from `services.exe` that inherits them from `wininit.exe`.
So my question: is it possible to update Windows service environment variables without Windows restart (and no `explorer.exe` restart as well)?